# Message misses a translation when i18nMissingTranslation is set to ignore

Tags: angular, internationalization

I'm trying to serve a web application in multiple languages however despite setting `i18nMissingTranslation` to `ignore`, it's still throwing errors on missing translations.

I've tried setting the `i18nMissingTranslation` in the `prod` config, in a single locale config defined like the official [i18n docs](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#merge-with-the-aot-compiler) and via command argument for example:

```sh
ng build --prod --i18nFormat xlf --i18nFile src/locale/messages.fr.xlf --i18nLocale fr --baseHref /fr/ --outputPath dist/fr/
```

Script to export messages:

```sh
"xi18n": "ng xi18n --i18n-locale en-US --output-path ./locale/ --out-file messages.en-US.xlf"
```

Config containing all locales:

```sh
"config": {
  "locales": "en-US fr nl"
}
```

Script to build languages:

```sh
"build": "ng build --prod",
"build:loop": "for lang in ${npm_package_config_locales}; do LANG=${lang} && npm run-script build:i18n; done",
"build:i18n": "npm run-script build -- --i18nFormat xlf --i18nFile src/locale/messages.${LANG}.xlf --i18nLocale ${LANG} --baseHref /${LANG}/ --outputPath dist/${LANG}/"
```

I'd expect this to allow me to export sites with missing target tags if not all translations have been translated yet.

Instead, I receive an error for each missing target tag:

```sh
ERROR in xliff parse errors:
Message {} misses a translation ("
```

Comment: It looks like a recent regression from the Angular CLI: it worked in 8.3.9, and does not in 8.3.16. With all the changes coming for i18n in version 9 and Ivy, I would guess the answer is either to rollback a few versions, or wait and upgrade to 9.

Comment: Is the Angular team aware of this? Same thing is happening to me. I downgraded with `npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.9` but the same error persists.

Comment: This appears to be posted multiple times on the issues with no fixes.

Comment: For now what I've done is instead of copy/paste the file for translations I didn't create it at all and let Weblate create the files for me. So in the translated ones instead of having missing target tags, I just don't have non translating strings what so ever. Which seems to work. And Weblate auto adds strings as they get translated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is instead of doing as instructed and copying the empty/template translations and updating the language to handle them, just manually create a new file and start putting new translations in from scratch.

You don't want to have entries with missing `target` tags, you just shouldn't have those entries what so ever if they haven't been translated yet.

Comment: Not happy that this is what I have to do for Angular 7.2.0 but I appreciate the answer